# How to propagate exceptions to the main thread from a QtConcurrent::run with promise

Tags: c++, qt, qtconcurrent

I'm experimenting with the [concurrent run with promise](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtconcurrentrun.html#concurrent-run-with-promise) functionality from Qt6. How can I catch, from the GUI thread, any exception thrown in the worker thread?

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_startTask_clicked()
{
    auto lambda = [](QPromise<void>& promise)
    {
        // Cancel the task if requested
        while (!promise.isCanceled())
        {
            // Do some long computation...

            if (<something-has-failed>)
                throw std::runtime_error("The task has failed");
        }
    };

    this->future = QtConcurrent::run(lambda);
    // Connect the watcher to the finished signal
    connect(&this->watcher, &QFutureWatcher<void>::finished, this, &MainWindow::on_taskFinished);
    this->watcher.setFuture(this->future);
}

void MainWindow::on_taskFinished()
{
    // How to catch the exception here?
}
```

I've tried by doing the following two things:

1. Adding `onFailed` in the `on_taskFinished`:

```
void MainWindow::on_taskFinished()
{
    this->future.onFailed([](const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::cout << ex.what();
    });
}
```

2. Adding `onFailed` after calling `QtConcurrent::run`:

```cpp
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_startTask_clicked()
{
    ...

    this->future = QtConcurrent::run(lambda)
        .onFailed([](const std::exception& ex)
        {
            std::cout << ex.what();
        });
    ...
}
```

In both cases the code passes from the `onFailed` block, but the exception is not the one thrown from the lambda, it looks like an empty default excetion (maybe something from Qt?), whose `what` content is `Unknown exception`.

Comment: How about using `std::async` and `std::future`? They handle exceptions implicitly. Anyway you should not use exceptions in Qt specific code.

Comment: If I used `std::async` I would loose the ability to connect a `QFutureWatcher` to handle the `finished` event, wouldn't I?

Comment: I have never tried but I would think that as long as the receiver lives in a thread with an event loop, sending signals from any thread (including non-Qt threads) should work. You may need to explicitly make the connection a `Qt::QueuedConnection`.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`onFailed`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qfuture.html#onFailed-1) with app context e.g.

```cpp
QtConcurrent::run(lambda).onFailed(qApp, [](const std::exception& ex) { 
    // executed on main thread
});
```

`qApp` is just macro for: [QCoreApplication::instance()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qcoreapplication.html#instance)

---

It is little bit tricky to use `QtConcurrent::run` prefer to use explicit context. Otherwise you may end up with issues like me when lambda executes so quick that you will "inherit wrong context".
E.g.

```
QtConcurrent::run(...).then( this may be executed on main thread "it depends" )
```

so prefer using: (or with QObject* context)

```
QtConcurrent::run(...).then(QtFuture::Launch::Async, always "in background")
```

Watchout for: `QUnhandledException`
Example how to handle it (to unwrap your exception):

```cpp
        .onFailed(qApp,
                  [](const QUnhandledException& ex) {
                      llog::error() << "QUnhandledException: " << (ex.exception() != nullptr)
                                    << " thread:" << std::this_thread::get_id();
                      try
                      {
                          std::rethrow_exception(ex.exception());
                      }
                      catch(const std::exception& rethrowEx)
                      {
                          llog::error() << "Rethrow exception: " << rethrowEx.what()
                                        << " thread:" << std::this_thread::get_id();

                          QMessageBox{QMessageBox::Icon::Critical,
                                      "QUnhandledException - std::exception",
                                      rethrowEx.what(),
                                      QMessageBox::StandardButton::Ok}
                              .exec();
                      }
                      catch(...)
                      {
                          llog::error() << "unknown handle";
                          QMessageBox{QMessageBox::Icon::Critical,
                                      "UnhandledException",
                                      "Error in unhandled",
                                      QMessageBox::StandardButton::Ok}
                              .exec();
                      }
                  })
```